# How to go From Dialog to BackStack Activity

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an Activity which have one button and two TextView.When i press button on activity a dialog box appear which has two editText and Done Button.I want when user give some value in EditText in dialog box and press DOne . Then This Dialog Box disappear and show the previous activity and set the text (Which i have got from the User in Dialog ) on Activity textView...How can i do this....

Comment: first try yoruself and shows us what you have done.

Comment: i Have tried it...But it give me error ..I have created a method in activity which take two arguments and set on text view ..And in the Dialog box i have called that method in Done button action listener.But its give error. Unfortunality....and app will close

Answer (score 0):

Refere this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) :

First Onclick() of Button to  call Your Activity Like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DIALOG_ACTIVITY.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

This will open Dialog Activity & OnClick() of Done Button Set Result in Onclick() method

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
  finish();
```

This Result you will get into Your Main Activity just override this result

```
    @Override
    Protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

& Dont forget to declare Activity in Manifest File Like this.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".DIALOG_ACTIVITY"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
```